# why does G evaluated at a certain x-µ gives me the CDF of x?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, mathematical-modeling

**So, I came across this excerpt of some notes.**

> Measurement Error Model:
>
> $X_i = µ + E_i, i = 1, 2, . . . , n$
>
> µ is constant parameter (e.g., real-valued, positive)
>
> $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, . . . , \epsilon_n$ i.i.d. with distribution
>   function $G(·)$
>
> (G does not depend on µ.)
>
> ⇒ $X_1, . . . , X_n$ i.i.d. with distribution function F(x) = G(x −
>   µ). $P = \{(µ, G) : µ ∈ R, G ∈ G \}$ where G is . . .
>
> $X_1, . . . , X_n$ i.i.d. with distribution function $F(x) = G(x −
> > µ)$.
>
> $P = \{(µ, G) : µ ∈ R, G ∈ G\}$ where $\mathcal{G} $ is . . .

---

I'm trying to understand the idea behind having $F(x)=G(x-µ)$.

Since we know that the error is distributed as G, why does G evaluated at a certain x-µ gives me the CDF of x ?

**My understanding of the whole thing:** *It is because x-µ feels like a deviation from the mean and while computing that number using the error CDF we will be getting the probability of observing that said value x*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer to the definition of CDF and the definition of $X_i$.

$$F(x) = P(X_i \le x) = P(\mu + E_i \le x) = P(E_i \le x-\mu) = G(x-\mu).$$